# Copied 'sample' text to clipboard using JAVA toolkit. Got 25 available data flavors

Tags: java, clipboard

I tried to retrieve available data flavors from the clipboard after copying the text to clipboard. I got 25 data flavors. Could some one help me to understand why this is happening ?

```js
Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
DataFlavor[] dataFlavors = clipboard.getAvailableDataFlavors();
System.out.println(dataFlavors.length);
for (int i = 0; i < dataFlavors.length; i++) {
  DataFlavor dataFlavor = dataFlavors[i];
  System.out.println(dataFlavor.getMimeType());
}
```

```html
25
application/x-java-serialized-object; class=java.lang.String
text/plain; class=java.io.Reader; charset=Unicode
text/plain; class=java.lang.String; charset=Unicode
text/plain; class=java.nio.CharBuffer; charset=Unicode
text/plain; class="[C"; charset=Unicode
text/plain; class=java.io.InputStream; charset=unicode
text/plain; class=java.nio.ByteBuffer; charset=UTF-16
text/plain; class="[B"; charset=UTF-16
text/plain; class=java.io.InputStream; charset=UTF-8
text/plain; class=java.io.InputStream
text/plain; class=java.nio.ByteBuffer; charset=UTF-8
text/plain; class="[B"; charset=UTF-8
text/plain; class=java.io.InputStream; charset=UTF-16BE
text/plain; class=java.nio.ByteBuffer; charset=UTF-16BE
text/plain; class="[B"; charset=UTF-16BE
text/plain; class=java.io.InputStream; charset=UTF-16LE
text/plain; class=java.nio.ByteBuffer; charset=UTF-16LE
text/plain; class="[B"; charset=UTF-16LE
text/plain; class=java.io.InputStream; charset=ISO-8859-1
text/plain; class=java.nio.ByteBuffer; charset=ISO-8859-1
text/plain; class="[B"; charset=ISO-8859-1
text/plain; class=java.io.InputStream; charset=US-ASCII
text/plain; class=java.nio.ByteBuffer; charset=US-ASCII
text/plain; class="[B"; charset=US-ASCII
application/x-java-text-encoding; class="[B"
```

Comment: So, which of the 25 different flavors describes your sample data.? Depending on which flavor you pick, different things happen with the copy and the paste.

Comment: I would like to know about the flavors present in clipboard. Ideally I should be getting only one flavor text/plain, but Java Clipboard returned multiple flavors. I am assuming these are different ways of obtaining the text format.

Comment: Probably your choice should be **text/plain; class=java.lang.String; charset=Unicode**.  Yes, the 25 different flavors possibly handle plain text differently depending on which flavor you choose.